# Poco library issues "Address family not supported" under FreeBSD

Tags: c++, freebsd, poco-libraries

We are exploring poco (pocoproject.org) library's HTTP server example. On windows it runs well but on FreeBSD issues "Address family not supported". On FreeBSD we used dynamic linking of installed via pkg poco-1.7.8

Source of this sample: 
https://github.com/toggl/toggldesktop/blob/master/third_party/poco/Net/samples/HTTPFormServer/src/HTTPFormServer.cpp

Any suggestions how we can fix it?

----- Update:

Original sample uses ipv4.

Same issue when I create ipv6 socket as follows:

```
        Poco::Net::SocketAddress addr("[fe80::a00:27ff:feb7:6b1a]:9980");

        if (addr.family() == static_cast<Poco::Net::IPAddress::Family>(Poco::Net::Impl::IPAddressImpl::IPv6)) {
            std::cout << "Addr: ipv6 " << std::endl;
        }
        else if (addr.family() == static_cast<Poco::Net::IPAddress::Family>(Poco::Net::Impl::IPAddressImpl::IPv4)) {
            std::cout << "Addr: ipv4 " << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Addr: something else (err)." << std::endl;
        }

        // set-up a server socket
        ServerSocket svs(addr);
```

Output

```
    Addr: ipv6
    Net Exception: Address family not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about poco, but the error message hints that it is an IPv6 issue.

Possible solutions:

- Disable IPv6 on FreeBSD
- Make your program IPv6 aware

See also this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388056/not-able-to-get-poco-1-6-1-or-1-7-6-to-bind-to-ipv6-with-netdatagramsocket)

Comment: IPv6 verison has same issue